# How to replace specified datetime with previous value but with addition of minute?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Here is my dataframe:

```
        dt                    country
0       Apr-14-2012 15:25:49  usa
1       Apr-14-2012 15:38:55  japan
2       Jan-00-0              france 
3       Apr-14-2012 16:05:07  uk
4       Apr-14-2012 16:18:13  ireland
```

And I want to replace that invalid value with previous value with addition of 8 minutes.

Here's desired dataframe:

```
        dt                    country
0       Apr-14-2012 15:25:49  usa
1       Apr-14-2012 15:38:55  japan
2       Apr-14-2012 15:46:55  france 
3       Apr-14-2012 16:05:07  uk
4       Apr-14-2012 16:18:13  ireland
```

I'm using this code:

```
df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt"],errors="coerce")
s = df["dt"].isnull()
df["dt"] = df["dt"].ffill()
df[s] -= pd.Timedelta(minutes=3)
print (df)
```

But I'm getting the output like this:

```
         dt                 country    
0        0 days 00:08:00    0 days 00:08:00
1        0 days 00:08:00    0 days 00:08:00
2        0 days 00:08:00    0 days 00:08:00
3        0 days 00:08:00    0 days 00:08:00
4        0 days 00:08:00    0 days 00:08:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are close, first change `bfill` for `ffill` and then set new column with condition `s` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt"],errors="coerce")

s = df["dt"].isnull()
df["dt"] = df["dt"].ffill()
df.loc[s, "dt"]+= pd.Timedelta(minutes=6)

print (df)
                   dt  country
0 2012-04-14 15:25:49      usa
1 2012-04-14 15:38:55    japan
2 2012-04-14 15:44:55   france
3 2012-04-14 16:05:07       uk
4 2012-04-14 16:18:13  ireland
```